# Solubility of Aluminium Fluoride in other other fluorine-containing solvents

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, solubility

I encountered a problem which required me to compare the solubility of $\ce{AlF3}$ in various solvents, namely $\ce{HF}$, $\ce{KF}$ & $\ce{KHF2}$ .

Further, this problem neither supplied, nor expected me to utilize  any solubility data. Infact, the problem only asked for the *expected* order, discounting any exceptional factors that may affect the actual numerical data.

My thoughts regarding this are as follows;

1. As $\ce{AlF3}$ is a Lewis acid, I expect it to have higher solubility in solvents which have lone pair containing donor ; possibly the fluoride ion from $\ce{KF}$ may be such a species
2. Further, in aqueous acidic solution, I expect a lower solubilty owing to common ion effect lowering the solubility
3. I am unsure and unclear regarding the action of $\ce{KHF2}$
4. Perceptions regarding H-bonding and complex formations also seem to apply, but I am unable to formulate these coherently

Given these points, can someone help me to organize my thoughts? I wish to know the lines along which I should guide my thoughts.

Comment: The Handbook of Chemistry and Physics mentions that $\ce{AlF3}$ is soluble in water, and that $\ce{AlF3·3H2O}$ is not soluble in water. So it is difficult to say if any of these substances will be soluble in $\ce{ KF, KHF2}$ or $\ce{HF}$.

Comment: See: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/65861/why-is-alf3-soluble-in-anhydrous-hf-only-in-the-presence-of-kf?r=SearchResults

Comment: @NilayGhosh thanks for the link to that question ; the answers over there answer my query.